# What's the fade condition of the following karambit?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Anyone knows what's the condition for the following fade (80/20, 90/10..) ?

Posterior Side:

[image]

Back Side:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of [this guide](http://csgoxchange.com/knives/karambit-knives/karambit-fade/):

Yours is closest to a 80/15/5, Pink/Purple/Gold.

[image]

Comment: Is it purple/pink/gold or pink/purple/gold?

Comment: It's pink purple gold, sorry.